# storing cookie or localStorage and picking it up after 'add to home screen'

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

We are part way through developing a professional app, the users login using iPhone safari, then they are supposed to add to home screen,. Once they load the app from their home screen it should remember their auth key which could be a cookie or a localStorage property.

I can't seem to get it to transfer, is this even possible?

Comment: Sorry, Yes this is possible! I had a stupid localStorage.clear() in my code which was making me think it wasn't working. So basically , if you user hits your website in mobile safari, just save them values /w localStorage and they can pick it up when they fire the app up  from the home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=I had a stupid localStorage.clear() in my code which was making me think it wasn't working. So basically , if you user hits your website in mobile safari, just save them values /w localStorage and they can pick it up when they fire the app up from the home screen

Comment: it seem that that same is not working for me I have stored my session in localStorage and every time I click the home screen I doesn't take the session in localStorage and land me on login page. can you place your Code will be very helpful